# Do you want to made changes in oracle forms

Tags: forms, oracle

I trying to update the existing fields through the forms and click on the SAVE(from the Main Menu), that time i want to show Alerts/Messages 'Do you want to made changes? Yes or No?" Can you please help me, how to use this ? What triggers to use , i set the properties of the Updated Items , Values are getting effected into the Table, But i want a messages please help

I checked all code like :System.Message_Level := '20';

My Database tables data are effected,I don't want any button,i want triggers to save the records

Answer (score 0):

You need to have Key-Commit form level trigger. In that trigger you write logic to show alert. The built in is Show_Alert(), if I remember this correctly. You need to create alerts under Alert(s) node in Forms builder. The alert can have one or up to 3 buttons. Check Show_Alert() in Forms help - Forms Builder -> Help. You can copy paste code from there. It is very easy to figure out. I do not remember exact syntax...

Comment: Thanks Art and sorry for the lately reply...could you please send me key-commit code please

Comment: I do not have examples as I currently do not have access to Forms Builder. All code in in Forms help, those are the best examples. Open Forms builder, create Key-Commit trigger - Form level. In the same way create Alert under Alert node. Open Forms builder help. Search for FIND_ALERT. Copy and paste the code. Replace alert name with the name of your alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Declare
     al_button number;
 Begin
       IF :System.Form_Status = 'CHANGED' THEN 
         al_button := Show_alert('SAVE'); 

        IF al_button = alert_button1 THEN 
          Commit_Form;  
        END IF; 
      END IF; 
End;
```

I have written in the KEY-COMMIT Trigger at the Form Level...